# What does it mean for a sequence of random vectors to converge to a random vector?

Tags: convergence, random-vector

I am reading about convergence of random variables from Wikipedia and I come across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20the,.).

> Note that the condition that $Y_n$ converges to a constant is important, if it were to converge to a random variable $Y$ then we wouldn't be able to conclude that $(X_n, Y_n)$ converges to $(X,Y)$.

This makes me conclude that
$\lim_{n \to \infty}(X_n, Y_n)$ and $(\lim_{n \to \infty}(X_n), \lim_{n \to \infty}(Y_n))$ are different things. Could you please help me understand why the two are different? Would really appreciate an example

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of $(X,Y)$ is not particularly well defined here unless one is almost surely constant.  In general you would need to know more than $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}X_n$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}Y_n$ can tell you.

For example suppose $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$.  You would not know from this whether $X$ and $Y$ are always equal to each other (correlation $1$) or independent of each other (correlation $0$) or something else.

So you would not know  the distribution of $(X,Y)$ or the limiting distribution of $(X_n,Y_n)$, at least without further information.

Comment: But, then how can we say that $(X_n, Y_n)$ always converges to $(X, Y)$ in probability if $X_n$ converges to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges to $Y$ in probability. Convergence in probability does not always mean convergence to a degenerate distribution with only one possible value. e.g: sequence $X + \mathcal(N)(0,1/n)$ converges in probability to $X$. Here also the notion of $(X,Y)$ is not well defined

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Pr\big(d_1(X_n,X) > \varepsilon\big) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Pr\big(d_1(Y_n,Y) > \varepsilon\big) = 0$ for some sensible 1D distance function $d_1$ such as $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ then it is reasonable to have this imply $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Pr\big(d_2((X_n,Y_n),(X,Y)) > \varepsilon\big) = 0$ for some sensible 2D distance function and prove it with an $\varepsilon-\delta$ argument